# JSON to HTML table with different rows and columns

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, html-table

I want to translate JSON into a HTML table but the JSON only contains the parent and children of each item (example given below).

```
[{
  "id": "1",
  "child": "2,3,4",
  "parent": "max"
},{
  "id": "2",
  "child": "5",
  "parent": "1"
},{
  "id": "3",
  "child": "5",
  "parent": "1"
},{
  "id": "4",
  "child": "8,9",
  "parent": "1"
},{
  "id": "5",
  "child": "6,7",
  "parent": "2,3"
},{
  "id": "6",
  "child": "min",
  "parent": "5"
},{
  "id": "7",
  "child": "min",
  "parent": "5"
},{
  "id": "8",
  "child": "min",
  "parent": "4"
},{
  "id": "9",
  "child": "min",
  "parent": "4"
}]
```

The table is also with multiple rows and columns (example given below).

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>6</td>
  <td rowspan="2">5</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td rowspan="4">1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>8</td>
  <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">4</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>9</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

What would the the best way to go about doing this? I’ve explored putting each the “children” tables into a separate table in the cell of a larger table but the main issue facing me is how to translate the parent-child relationship to tables especially when it’s tricky in cases like the relationship between cell 2,3 and 5. I know it will involve some form of recursion but I can’t figure out how it would work. Thank you so much!

I know that there are some other questions talking about JSON to HTML table but I believe none of them mention about uneven rows and columns.

Comment: Your example Json is not actually valid Json... Where does this 'Json' come from?

Comment: Based on what criterion would the vertical line, in the table, between items 8, 9 and 4, be placed underneath the vertical line between items 6, 7 and 5 and not underneath the vertical line between items 2, 3 and 5? Or, in other words, why is item 4 two columns wide, and not items 8 and 9?

Comment: Updated JSON @Erik

Comment: check some family tree javascript builders to get an idea

Comment: In this case, as long as it satisfies the criteria of the parent-child relationship, the column count of the cells don't matter (item 4 OR item 8 and 9 can be 2 columns long) @KIKOSoftware

Comment: sorry got a bit caught up with work, can I modify the Json a bit as long as the data stays the same?

Comment: Yup sure, thanks for your help! @Erik

Comment: I'm afraid I can't find an elegant solution because a child may span multiple parents according to your sample Json.  You `can` write this out longhand where you place each block on a grid with a width based on their parents and left-to-right starting position based on any block placed earlier on the row.

Comment: Hmm, I'll go try something like that and explore some more options, thanks for your help @Erik